# update array of object of object MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have this **model**

```
student: {
   package:{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Package',
   },
   history: [
    {
      package: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Package',
      },
      orderDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: new Date().toLocaleDateString('id'),
      },
      Status: {
        type: String,
        default: 'Pending',
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

What I want to do is that I want to update `Student.package` and `Student.history` in 1 pass

I create this method in my **model**

```
StudentSchema.methods.updatePackage= function(idPackage) {
  this.package = idPackage;
  return this.save();
};

StudentSchema.methods.updateHistory= function(idPackage) {
  this.history.push(idPackage);
  return this.save();
};
```

and I'm trying to do something like this in my **controller**

```
buyPack: async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      let dataStudent = await Student.findById('5b83443040e3751bb4e32a21');
      await dataStudent.updatePackage(req.body);
      await dataStudent.updateHistory(req.body);
      return res.json(dataStudent);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      next(err);
    }
  },
```

I think the **first** and **second** methods are wrong, but I have tried to figure it out in almost half of day, but still no luck. What is the best way to achieve my goals?

Do I make my model wrong? or do the methods I created are wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose model rename with plural .. and you refer with singular with "S", "Package" change it to "Packages"

Comment: which one? both?

Comment: yes both,  first check the collection name is plural

Comment: oke now I got another error saying `ValidationError: Student validation failed: package: Cast to ObjectID failed for value "{ package: '5b76586b4d4b86370c10e45e' }" at path "package"`

Comment: oh the first problem is solved, I just need to do something like `idPackage.package`, but how about the 2nd problems? am i doing it correctly? `updateHistory`

Comment: one more thing . i notice .. req.body is Object , you have to pass Mongoose.ObjectId(idPackage.package)